# nodejs callback not work

Tags: json, node.js

it is the code

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require("request");

function getData(city, callback){
    var urlData = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city;
    callback.write("urlRequest : "+urlData+"\n");


    request(urlData, function(error, response, body, callback) {
        if(callback && typeof(callback) === "function")
            callback.write(body);
    });
}

// create http server
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var query = require('url').parse(req.url).query;
    var app = require('querystring').parse(query).city;
    // content header
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    if(app)
        getData(app, res);
    else 
        res.write("Use url:port?city=xxxx");

    res.end();
}).listen(8124);
console.log('Server running at 8124');
```

I need to print what I get, I tried to use a callback but did not succeed. I do not understand what is wrong. I think the error is in this line or the function is wrong

```
request(urlData, function(error, response, body, callback) {
```

Comment: Did not succeed how? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no errors but not write the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name of the second parameter of the getData function to something different (callback -> res). You have a names collision inside of the request call (callback is a function and you want to access the res variable).

By the way, if the request is asynchronous, it's not going to work, because you call res.end() before the res.write() is called.

Edit:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require("request");

function getData(city, res){ // Here
    var urlData = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city;
    res.write("urlRequest : "+urlData+"\n"); // Here


    request(urlData, function(error, response, body, callback) {
        if(callback && typeof(callback) === "function")
            res.write(body); // Here
        res.end(); // Here
    });
}

// create http server
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var query = require('url').parse(req.url).query;
    var app = require('querystring').parse(query).city;
    // content header
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    if(app) {
        getData(app, res);
    }
    else {
        res.write("Use url:port?city=xxxx");
        res.end(); // Here
    }
}).listen(8124);
console.log('Server running at 8124');
```

Comment: does not work, I want to access the write method of res

Comment: thanks, it works! but if I had to change the if 

if(res) res.write(body);

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. The res variable is always accessible. The real problem is with the callback. You don't call it so you can remove the if statement. But if you called it you would have to keep the statement on its place:

if(callback && typeof(callback) === "function") callback(body);

But you really know the value of the res variable.

Comment: but if I use if (callback && typeof (callback) === "function") does not print the result :/

Comment: Because you put there the res.write. That's wrong. If you need to do something with callback, put there the condition and then call the callback. If not, just call res.write without any condition.